# Multiple choice question about possible arguments of a piecewise function given its value

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions

> $$f(x,y)=\begin{cases} x+y& x+y<1\\
> 0 & x+y=1\\
> xy& x+y>1\end{cases}$$

If $f(x,1/2)= 3/4$, then which of the following can be the value of x?

1) $1/4$

2) $3/2$

3) $3/4$

4) Both 2) and 3)

5) Both 1) and 2)

According to me since value of $f(x,y)<1$ hence $x+1/2<1$

So for that value of $x$ can only be $1/4$

But answer is $5$th option. How?

Comment: Which $>$ is supposed to be $<$ in the definition of $f$?

Comment: When $x = 3/2$ then $x+y > 1$ and $xy=3/4$.

Comment: I am really sorry @Shuri2060

Comment: Just because $f(x,1/2)<1$ doesn't mean you can assume $x+1/2<1$.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews, sorry, you're right, i mistyped!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no reason to compare $f(x,1/2)$ with $1$. We need to compare $x+1/2$ with $1$, because in order to see which expression $f(x,1/2)$ is defined as, we must know whether $x+1/2>1$, $x+1/2=1$, or $x+1/2<1$. Let's split among these three cases:

If $x+1/2=1$, then we would have $f(x,1/2)=0\ne3/4$.
Since this can't happen, we must know that $x\ne1/2$.

If $x+1/2>1$, then $x>1/2$ and $3/4=f(x,1/2)=x(1/2)=x/2$. This implies that $x=3/2$, which shows that (2) is a possibility.

If $x+1/2<1/2$, then $x<1/2$ and $3/4=f(x,1/2)=(x)+(1/2)=x+1/2$. This implies that $x=1/4$, which shows that (1) is a possibility.

Therefore the correct answer is (5).

Comment: I did not understand @JohnGriffin

Comment: @SakuziMarkel I've added a bit more explanation. Please let me know which parts you are having trouble understanding.

Comment: how is f(x,1/2)=x(1/2) @JohnGriffin

Comment: @SakuziMarkel Because in that line, we are assuming that $x+1/2>1$. The definition of $f(a,b)$ when $a+b>1$ is $ab$, so $f(x,1/2)=x(1/2)$.

Comment: You are so smart! Thanks @JohnGriffin

Answer (score 1):

I suspect 'Both 1 and 2' means the options `1` and `2` rather than the values $1$ and $2$. Which would make perfect sense - they both work.

The question is also slightly poorly worded. Options `1` and `2` are technically correct.

---

That aside, as noted by the comments/other answer, your working isn't quite correct if you're trying to find all possible solutions for $x$.